# Redialing when number is busy

Tags: calls

How can I auto redial when number is busy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 doesn't support this feature, [although it has been requested many times by users](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions?query=redial).